# how to set PorterDuffXfermode, the result is bias too much

Tags: android, android-canvas

Following is my program and reference picture.

Program :

```
int width = src.getWidth();
int height = src.getHeight();
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas (bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setDither(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY)); 
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAlpha(35);
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);
```

Reference picture :

[image]

I used above program to add a light transparent red color (with alpha) to the photo. But I am not clear why the photo changed to deep deep red. The "ideal result" is made by Photoshop. I just add a red layer before the original photo. And than change to a low transparence and MULTIPLY.

Are they not the same processing concept or my program has anything wrong? Does it can't use Mode.MULTIPLY to create the "ideal result"? Can anybody give some opinion to me?

thanks thanks thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN));
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setAlpha(95);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);
mCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), paint);
```

With mode `Lighten` and Alpha as 95 I'm getting something nearer to your requirement.

Result:

[image]

Comment: @hotverydpicy First of all, thank you for your reply and help. As before, I had try to use Lighten mode too. Same with yours, it is nearer the result in this case. However, I hope clearly how to use MULTIPLY mode and the limitation. Also, if I changed to the other photo, Lighten mode may not have nearer result with MULTIPLY mode. More importantly, I would like to know why it changed to deep red which not equal to photoshop. I can't figure out.

Comment: Ya agree with you @John, this is happening because in photoshop we have option `FILL` and `OPACITY` while here what is happening is that first image and Red both get Multiply then it setting alpha so which leads the difference you can see.

Comment: Why they both get Multiply? I have already draw the src photo before set to Multiply mode. Theoretically, it just  affect the Red color only. is it right?

Comment: ya you are right, it must affect Red only. will see to it what we can do further :) good task.